Sts. Mary & Joseph's house = Sts. Joachim & Anna's house?
Is the House of Loreto (originally in Nazareth, but later miraculously transported to Loreto, Italy) Sts. Mary & Joseph's house or Sts. Joachim & Anna's, or was it both of theirs?
Did St. Joseph inherit the house from his in-laws?

Down-voter, please explain your down-vote.

Not I, but I would like the question better if it had included quotations of the relevant parts of the two links rather than expecting me to read those other pages. Perhaps that's why.

It's claimed that it was first Sts. Joachim & Anna's, and later Sts. Mary & Joseph's.

Sts. Mary and Joseph's house = Sts. Joachim and Anna's house?
Is the House of Loreto (originally in Nazareth, but later miraculously transported to Loreto, Italy) Sts. Mary & Joseph's house or Sts. Joachim & Anna's, or was it both of theirs?
Did St. Joseph inherit the house from his in-laws?
These questions are impossible to verify historically. Although it was a common custom for the bride to join the groom’s father’s household, rather than the groom and the bride establishing their own household. So, if the bride and groom were of a marriageable age, the groom would return to his father’s house after the betrothal to prepare a bridal chamber.
Whether these customs were does with Joseph and Mary, we have no historical evidence to indicate whether the House of Loreto was St. Joseph’s and May’s house or if it was of St. Joseph’s family or St. Joachim’s and St. Anne’s home.
All we is that the House of Loreto was traditionally held to be located in Loreto and that the Virgin Mary at time dwelt there.
The Holy See maintains that the Holy House Mary was born and lived as a woman, a wife and a mother.

In Holy House Mary was born and lived as a woman, a wife and a mother: this is why it represents a home for every family that there finds support, comfort and hope in difficulties between those three walls. Within those walls Mary said her Yes to God, a strong and courageous Yes, which is an example of life for the pilgrim: the ability to say yes when being called, both to marriage, to consecration or even of social commitment and for the common good. - The Holy House from Nazareth to Loreto



The House itself consists of three stone walls. It is a plain stone structure, with a door on the north side and a window on the west. The size is 31 by 13 feet (9.4 m × 4.0 m)[8] (or 9.52 m × 4.10 m × 4.30 m (31.2 ft × 13.5 ft × 14.1 ft)) high. - Basilica della Santa Casa

